# Community "Groups" feature (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, social-networking

Are there any good examples/plugins that enable users to create groups within a community application. For example, I would like to create a Group class and add it to something like Community Engine (http://communityengine.org/). Essentially, users need to be able to create and manage groups that other users can join (much like Facebook Pages). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins can be helpful to add specific functionality to an app but beware of using plugins that offer way more than is needed.  The Community Engine looks like it offers a significant number of features but may be more than just the groups aspect you're looking to add.  It might be worthwhile whiteboarding out what specific ideas you have before investing in integration of an existing library.  Integration of something that doesn't fit perfectly will eventually take more effort.